# Access through SSH to a SELinux enabled machine

Tags: centos7, selinux

first question here!

I have a CentOS 7 virtual machine using SELinux in my job's local network in which I want to install OKD.
The issue is that OKD requires SELinux to be enabled, and enabling it means getting kicked out from the machine, since everytime I try to SSH into it, I get a "/bin/bash: Permission denied" message.

Is there any way to configure the access to the machine via SSH so that I could connect to it, preferably with a non-root user, and then change into a root user once the connection has been established?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you relabeled the filesystem after enabling SELinux?

Comment: I did not... Is that a necessary step?

Comment: That's possibly why you're getting an error. I always have SELinux enabled and it's never stopped SSH from working, I've certainly never needed to resort to creating custom rules. IIRC you just need to do `touch /.autorelabel` before rebooting after enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is messed up in your environment, I would suggest you to go through [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-troubleshooting-fixing_problems#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow) reference.
So, per my understanding you need to find the correct policies for ssh and add it to make it work you can use **audit2allow** and **sealert** to dig more into issue, still need help paste your ssh related logs from audit.log in your question.